# XCode changing default behaviour of comment shortcuts

Tags: xcode, swift

Is there a way to customise XCode comment actions. Example:
original

```
func thisfunc() {
     var x = 5
}
```

when commented (cmd + /)

```
func thisfunc() {
     // var x = 5
}
```

not

```
func thisfunc() {
//     var x = 5
}
```

In the default behaviour XCode puts the comment in the beginning of the line but I want it to be like the first commented example (like sublime text comment blocks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can customize XCode the way you want. However there's still a way to do it by the steps are (1) selecting commented code (2) `cmd + [` (3) `cmd + /` (4) `ctrl + i`. Have a try and this is not that complicated.

Comment: Can I make a macro shortcut which does this?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to do that since each step may need to execute different times depends on different situations.